# speech recognition without google installed in android device

Tags: android, google-play-services, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm making an app for an android device that doesn't include Google apps(not even google play services). But as I have seen everywhere there's not a single speech recognition better than google because either they are offline (so the app size increases for good accuracy) or they don't have better open-source services. So I want to access google's speech recognition without having google apps installed in the watch. Can google services be accessible online without installing? Any help is appreciated!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google speech recognition API.
(https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics)
It supports Restful API or gRPC API.
API is not free of charge. But I think it will give the performance you looking for.

Hyo

Comment: but doesn't it require google search engine or Google play services on the device

Comment: I earlier tried using Vosk speech recognition but the 50 MB language model was not much accurate and higher MB models were taking a lot of space. any help regarding this?